# Windows Event Log : Event template - Output type: win:Xml

Tags: winapi

I am making Windows event log for my application that support Vista and above. I have a manifest created for each event, but I get a issue with the output type of win:Xml.
Below is what I specify for the data in event template.

```
<data name="StackTrace" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="win:Xml">
</data>
```

I would like to set the StackTrace to be displayed as XML format in the Event logs. StackTrace must be input with well-formed XML. However, I still see it displayed as string(xs:string) in the Event Log viewer.

Do you know what I did wrong? How can I make it properly?

Below if update for my code:

```
const int NUM_OF_DATADESC = 6;
EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR eventDataDesc[NUM_OF_DATADESC];
evDesc.Level = uLevel;
evDesc.Channel = nChannel;
evDesc.Keyword |= uKeyword;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATADESC; i++)
{
if (strings[i] != NULL)
    EventDataDescCreate(&eventDataDesc[i], strings[i],    ((ULONG)wcslen(strings[i])+1)*sizeof(WCHAR));
else
    EventDataDescCreate(&eventDataDesc[i], L"", sizeof(WCHAR));
}
BOOL s = WriteEvent(evDesc,NUM_OF_DATADESC,&eventDataDesc[0]);


BOOL WriteEvent(EVENT_DESCRIPTOR eventID,DWORD userDataCount,PEVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR     userData)
{
REGHANDLE hPub = NULL;
ULONG res = EventRegister(&MYCOMPANE_MYAPP_MYCOMPONENT, NULL, NULL, &hPub);    
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res){
    return FALSE;
}

res = EventWrite(hPub, &eventID, userDataCount, userData);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res){
 return FALSE;
}
EventUnregister(hPub);

return TRUE;
}
```

The code is working fine, but only issue with output type = win:Xml.

Comment: If the log only display `string(xs:string)`, then there's something wrong with your code. But since the relevant code isn't provided, it's impossible to find the exact problem. You may want to update your question to include all the relevant detals.

Comment: i added the code. could you please take a look and give me advice. Thanks.